# How can we set a large UIImage on small UIImageview

Tags: iphone

I am using imagview with size of 320X320 to display large image (350 X 783).

While placing the large image into the imageview, the image looks squeezed, compressed something not like the quality one.

My question is, how can I make the large image into small with as good quality as the original image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size {
    // Create a bitmap graphics context
    // This will also set it as the current context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    // Draw the scaled image in the current context
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    // Create a new image from current context
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // Pop the current context from the stack
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    // Return our new scaled image
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set your image view a proper content mode, like that

```
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Thanks, This issue has fixed now

Comment: Just to note this does not prevent memory issues when dealing with multiple large images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
    UIImage* sourceImage = "yourImage";
    CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(80,80);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    yourImageView.image=newImage;
```